# Using Capybara matchers in a controller spec with ActionController::TestResponse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rspec, capybara

I'm calling `render_views` in my rspec controller spec so I can test the content of the response directly rather than using separate view specs.

Sure enough the view is rendered and returned in `response.body`.

The problem is how to actually parse the content of the page in an expressive way. I'm trying to use Capybara matchers like `has_content`, `has_field` etc. which work fine in the request specs, but they don't work with `ActionController::TestResponse` or with the string returned from `.body`.

Where's the rspec API for parsing the view?

What's the point of `render_views` if I can't inspect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to spec rendered views I suggest to do that in a request/acceptance/feature spec, not controller. Controller specs should be treated more like unit specs for controllers. render_views can be used if you want to make sure that a view renders without any problems, but you shouldn't go any deeper in terms of speccing that view.

Comment: Yup, good call Solnic. Looks like digging into the view in a controller spec is trouble and slows the tests down significantly. I'm keeping the UI stuff in the request spec and primarily using the controller spec to test assigns.